# asp.net page postbacks when mouse is moved over embedded youtube flash video

Tags: asp.net, youtube, mouse, postback, move

I am developing a site in which youtube video’s will be added to asp.net page using the  HTML code given at youtube.com site.  When I run the program, in the web page youtube video is displayed.  But the strange thing is when I move mouse over the video display area the page postbacks happens.  I am able to find this when I run the program in debug mode.

To exactly reproduce the scenario, I am writing the steps which I have done in my project.

1) In visula studio 2010 > Open asp.net web application project (with c# as language)
2) add some page, say cat.aspx
3) in cat.aspx write the code as below

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblVideo" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
</form>
```

4) in cat.aspx.cs, in page_load even write the following line

lblVideo.Text = "<iframe width=\"620\" height=\"349\"   src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/WoTsE7pbuKg\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";

5)you can replace the above  given by youtube.com, but be sure to set "http:" and escape " with \" as how I have done.(to get  HTML code for any youtube video, visit www.youtube.com, click on any video or a famous song, below the video a menu "share" will be displayed, click on it, then another option "Embed" will be displayed, click on it, you will be presented with  code)

6)Now run your web app project, you can see, youtube video is displayed.

7)Now run with break point set in Page_load event, now move mouse over the video display area, you can see for each time the mouse enters the video display area, a postback happens.

8) I have latest flash installed in firefox and InternetExplorer, this problem happens only in firefox and IE, not in chrome.  And this problem happens only when we use Updatepanel.  I also found that page does not postback (IsPostBack) is false when every time the control hits the codebehind.  It is like page is requested for the first time as how we type the url in the address bar and press enter

I tried using asp:PostBackTrigger and asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger
Both are not giving solution to the problem, because what happens is not postback, it is fresh page request

Many Thanks in advance to anybody who try to help or give solution.

Comment: I think I'm missing something here: in step 4 are you trying to set the label to an iframe tag? Because it's incomplete. When I try to reproduce it using your steps (fixed the iframe html), no postbacks happen on mouse movements

Comment: Hi Stephen, thanks for your efforts, now I have updated the question, I am new to stackoverflow, I dont know that there are some restrictions in using iframe or xml tags, are you able to see the video getting displayed inside asp.net label?, are you using updatepanel and scriptmanager?, are you using .net 4.0, visual studio 2010? I feel the bug could in Ajax Extensions which gives updatepanel functionality

Comment: Yes to all of the above, edited the iframe tag to your new one, and still cannot reproduce your described behaviour, sorry.